# Rails server works, Rails console does not. `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError) -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring

I'm using rvm on mac osx 10.9.5:
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

Current ruby version in RVM:

=* ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]

I'm not sure what exactly caused this behaviour, it could be that I updated homebrew.

I also tried to disable spring by removing it from the gemfile, no luck. Also note the paths in the stacktrace, for Spring it points to 2.1.3 instead of 2.2.3. What could be going on here ?

```
$ rails c
Ignoring libv8-3.16.14.13 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine libv8 --version 3.16.14.13
Ignoring libv8-3.16.14.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine libv8 --version 3.16.14.11
Ignoring oj-2.14.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine oj --version 2.14.0
/Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.4.4/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Laurens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

$ rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Answer (score 2):

After lots of trial and error, got it working by doing the following:

1. In my rails project folder there was an invisible file called
   ".bundle", I deleted this file, it somehow had references to 2.1.3 .
2. Ran `bundle install`
3. Ran `spring stop`
4. Ran `spring binstub --all`

(In the meanwhile I also updated my xcode, but not sure if this had any effect.)

After this, rails c worked without the pristine & bundle errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just update spring to latest (1.6.4)
see 
https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/456
for references

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this command?

```
gem pristine --all
```

If it does not help, try this one:

```
rvm get stable
```

You should also call your rails console command in the context of the bundle:

```
bunde exec rails console
```

Comment: Tried them both, didn't work, actually got it working now after lots of trial and error, will answer the question.

Comment: Also, both `bundle exec rails c` and `rails c` didn't work, returned the same error as posted in my question